# Sorting only a single column in CVS table

Tags: sorting, awk

Is there a single step way using awk, sort or something equal to sort or reverse a single column of a multi-column CSV table while maintaining the rest in the same order they are?

For example,I have:

```
6, 45, 9
5, 47, 6
4, 46, 7
3, 48, 4
2, 10, 5
1, 11, 1
```

and would like to have:

```
1, 45, 9
2, 47, 6
3, 46, 7
4, 48, 4
5, 10, 5
6, 11, 1
```

So, only the first column is sorted and the rest are in their previous order.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1 file | sort) <(cut -d, -f2- file)
```

Answer (score 1):

awk one-liner

```
awk -F, '{c[NR]=$1;l[NR]=$2", "$3}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) print c[NR-i+1]", "l[i]}' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo "6, 45, 9
5, 47, 6
4, 46, 7
3, 48, 4
2, 10, 5
1, 11, 1"|awk -F, '{c[NR]=$1;l[NR]=$2", "$3}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) print c[NR-i+1]", "l[i]}'
1,  45,  9
2,  47,  6
3,  46,  7
4,  48,  4
5,  10,  5
6,  11,  1
```

Comment: Should note this doesn't sort the first column it just prints it in reverse, won't work with unsorted data.

Comment: @sudo_O yes you are right. I saw "sort or something equal to sort or reverse a single column " in OP's question.

Comment: @Kent darn, I just posted the same thing THEN saw yours. +1 and deleted mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `GNU awk` here's a one liner:

```
$ gawk '{s[NR]=$1;c[NR]=$2 $3}END{for(i=0;++i<=asort(s);)print s[i] c[i]}' file
1,45,9
2,47,6
3,46,7
4,48,4
5,10,5
6,11,1
```

If not, here's an `awk` script that implements a simple bubble sort:

```
{ # read col1 in sort array, read others in col array
  sort[NR] = $1
  cols[NR] = $2 $3
}
END { # sort it with bubble sort
    do {
    haschanged = 0
    for(i=1; i < NR; i++) {
      if ( sort[i] > sort[i+1] ) {
    t = sort[i]
    sort[i] = sort[i+1]
    sort[i+1] = t
    haschanged = 1
      }
    }
  } while ( haschanged == 1 )

  # print it
  for(i=1; i <= NR; i++) {
      print sort[i] cols[i]
  }
}
```

Save it to a file `sort.awk` and do `awk -f sort.awk file`:

```
$ awk -f sort.awk file
1,45,9
2,47,6
3,46,7
4,48,4
5,10,5
6,11,1
```